# Apanding external HTML to a react component is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Basically I want to add an static HTML to a react component from external script.

So I'm saving the reference of `this` to window variable as follows:

```
let { PropTypes } = React;

export default class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    let frmTrgt={};
    frmTrgt.refff=this;
    console.log("tthis: ",this);
    window.bdyRefrence=frmTrgt;
  }
  static defaultProps = {
    items: []
  };

  static propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.body}>
        <h1 className={styles.header}>React Seed</h1>
        <p>This is an example seed app, powered by React, ES6 &amp; webpack.</p>
        <p>Here is some example data:</p>
        <Menu items={this.props.items} />
        <div>
          <h1>Dynamic Content</h1>
          <div id="myDynamicContent"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and in my script tag in INDEX.html( Outside Script) I'm doing like following:

```
function addPHtml() {
      try {
        window.bdyRefrence.refff.refs.formTarget.insertAdjacentHTML("<p id='mhere'>paragraph 2</p>");
      }catch (err){
        console.log("err: ",err);
      }
    }
```

but when I'm calling addPHtml it is giving following error:

```
err:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined
    at addPHtml ((index):19)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: 'Window' behaves different in React, you can access via "componentDidMount()" method, but not in the constructor. You have to render it and then once the component has been rendered, use window object

Comment: Same error It didn't work even after moving to componentDidMount()

Comment: where is your formTarget ref ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your trying to do is not the correct way to insert the element in React, still for you requirement please refer below mentioned code

Your render function should be like

```
return(
    <div>
    <div ref="formTarget"></div>
    <h1 >React Seed</h1>
    <p>This is an example seed app, powered by React, ES6 &amp; webpack.</p>
    <p>Here is some example data:</p>
    <div>
      <h1>Dynamic Content</h1>
      <div id="myDynamicContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
```

Please check Demo here [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xC5f0EVRU6OTGubBIzS?p=preview)

In case using new React syntax (Createclass is deprecated now) use

```
window.refferedItem.refs.formTarget.getDOMNode().insertAdjacentHTML
```

Comment: in my case it is throwing error 'window.bdyRefrence1.refs.formTarget.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function'

Comment: It worked after replacing by 'window.bdyRefrence1.refs.formTarget.getDOMNode().insertAdjacentHTML('

Comment: @AkhileshKumar: If I update the Plunker then it's not working over there so you can accept the answer because plunker is working fine and if anyone refer then he/she will write the syntax based on the ref he/she declare in their component :)

Comment: So in ur answer mention if using createReactClass then they should use window.bdyRefrence1.refs.formTarget.getDOMNode().insertAdja‌​centHTML